# pandas - find rows if values in column of dtype list (object) has specific value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Given a data frame like below

```
   A  B  C-1  D  BTP           Type C1           Type C2
0  0  1    0  0    0               NaN          [Type B]
1  0  2    1  1   14          [Type B]          [Type B]
2  0  3    2  2   28          [Type A]          [Type B]
3  0  4    3  3   42  [Type A, Type B]  [Type A, Type B]
4  0  5    4  4   56          [Type A]  [Type A, Type B]
```

want to fetch rows with value `Type A` for column `Type C1` and `42` for column `BTP` which should return row index 3.

Tried the following, but gives an error `KeyError: False`

```
df.loc[(df['BTP'] == 42) & ('Type A' in df['Type C1'])]
```

What I'm ultimately trying to do is to fetch row that will match the above condition (which would be a single row) and extract the values for columns `B` and `C-1` as a dict like `{'B_val': 4, 'C_val': 3}`

Comment: does `Type C1` and `Type C2` list or string?

Comment: both are of `list` type (object)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```
>>> type_a = df['Type C1'].apply(pd.Series).eq('Type A').any(1)
>>> df[df['BTP'].eq(42) & type_a]
   A  B  C-1  D  BTP           Type C1           Type C2
3  0  4    3  3   42  [Type A, Type B]  [Type A, Type B]
```

Answer (score 1):

Use, [`Series.str.join`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.join.html) to join the lists in column `Type C1`, then we could be able to use [`Series.str.contains`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.contains.html) on this column to check whether the given string i.e `Type A` is present in the series or not, finally we can filter the rows of dataframe using the boolean `mask`:

```
mask = df['BTP'].eq(42) & df['Type C1'].str.join('-').str.contains(r'\bType A\b')
df = df[mask]
```

Result:

```
# print(df)

   A  B  C-1  D  BTP           Type C1           Type C2
3  0  4    3  3   42  [Type A, Type B]  [Type A, Type B]
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved this with a custom function to return a list of True/False values for each row, based on whether the list under consideration contains 'Type A' or not.

```
# Check if elem is present in column 'col'
def has_elem(col, elem):
    result = []
    for c in col:
        if elem in c:
            result.append(True)
        else:
            result.append(False)
    return result

# Filter
df.loc[(df['BTP'] == 42) & has_elem(df['Type_C1'], 'Type A'), :]
```

The reason your code doesn't work is because the 2nd filter clause `'Type A' in df['Type_C1']` looks for membership of the string `'Type A'` in the Series object `df['Type_C1']`, and consequently returns `False`. Instead, you need to return a sequence of True/False values, 1 for each row in your dataframe.